# Jhipster: run junittest without webserver

Tags: spring, testing, spring-boot, jhipster

This is a question about testing.

I want to test my service and need the injections to work but I don't need a **webservice** starting up.

This is my code :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyWebApp.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public class MyUserServiceTest {

@Inject
private MyUserService myUserService;

@Test
public void testRegister(){
    myUserService.registerNew();
}

}
```

when I run it like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyUserServiceTest {
```

I get this error:

```
Cannot load an ApplicationContext with a NULL 'contextLoader'
```

like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyWebApp.class)
public class MyUserServiceTest {
```

I get:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
```

when I add the `@WebAppConfiguation` the test works but I get the **webapplication** running which takes a lot of time.

i now use my MyWebAppTest.class which is like this:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ JHipsterProperties.class, LiquibaseProperties.class })

public class MyWebAppTest {  }
```

but stil the webservice is started....

Answer (score 1):

In `src/test/java`, you could define a `MyTestContext` class that would exclude some configurations but define a spring application context with enough dependencies to make your test pass.

```
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyTestContext.class)
```

You can start by defining it similarly to `MyWebApp`, make your test pass and then exclude some configurations until you reach the minimal set of dependencies, if your `MyTestContext` class is very specific to your service test you could also define as a static inner class of your test, this is a common pattern in Spring tests.

Comment: i removed as much as i could but i think the autoconfiguration still does to much. it still does startup a webserver which i do not need.


@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class, MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class })
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ JHipsterProperties.class, LiquibaseProperties.class })
public class MyAppTest {

}